# Facebook Developer PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Hello guys I am having problem with integrating my facebook app. I have created an app, and a local app that will connect to my facebook app getting details from the user. Check my codes below:

```
<?php

 session_start();

 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );


 use Facebook\FacebookSession;
 use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
 use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
 use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
 use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
 use Facebook\GraphObject;
 use Facebook\GraphUser;
 use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

 $id = 'xxxx';
 $secret = 'xxx;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/facebook/');

try{
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}catch(Exception $e){

}

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);

try{
    $session->Validate($id, $secret);
}catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
    $session = '';
}
}

if(isset($session)){
$_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
echo "Login Successful<br>";
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
echo "Hi " . $graph->getName();

}
else{
echo "<a href = " . $helper->getLoginUrl() . ">Login With Facebook</a>";
}

?>
```

Now the problem is when I click the **Login with Facebook** I got this error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Entities\AccessToken' not found in C:\wamp\www\facebook\Facebook\FacebookSession.php on line 74**

How can I get it to work? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to suggest that you do not have all the required files - are you certain that you have downloaded and referenced the SDK correctly in your code?

Comment: yes I have downloaded the latest SDK from developers.google.com.

Comment: Well that may be your problem - You should get the SDK from **Facebook** not Google ;)

Comment: ooops sorry, I meant developers.facebook.com..lol

Comment: You should simply use the autoloader that is provided together with the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the very latest version of the Facebook PHP SDK, and change your code include the following:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
```